# Is my Ubuntu vulnerable to SambaCry?

Tags: package-management, samba, security

I read these two threads:

1. [Warning! Hackers Started Using "SambaCry Flaw" to Hack Linux Systems](https://thehackernews.com/2017/06/linux-samba-vulnerability.html)
2. [7-Year-Old Samba Flaw Lets Hackers Access Thousands of Linux PCs Remotely](https://thehackernews.com/2017/05/samba-rce-exploit.html)

[image: SambaCry]

And I got a little bit worried, is my Ubuntu machine safe? Or am I vulnerable to this vulnerability?

The second article mentioned that:

> The flaw actually resided in the way Samba handled shared libraries.

The other thing that they say is all versions from versions 3.5.0 onwards since 2010 are vulnerable.

> At that time, nearly 485,000 Samba-enabled computers were found to be exposed on the Internet, and researchers predicted that the SambaCry-based attacks also have potential to spread just like WannaCry ransomware widely.
>   [(here)](https://thehackernews.com/2017/06/linux-samba-vulnerability.html).

I don't have a samba server however I've got `samba-libs` package installed.

What, if anything, should I do?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should have a samba server running to be vulnerable to this bug which you don't have.

This vulnerability already has been patched, its CVE-ID is: "[CVE-2017-7494](https://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2017-7494)":

> Samba since version 3.5.0 is vulnerable to remote code execution vulnerability, allowing a malicious client to upload a shared library to a writable share, and then cause the server to load and execute it.

So what you should do is a system upgrade if you didn't have done it already, then you are safe to go.

Check your `apt's` "history logs" to see if your Ubuntu recently received any upgrade for samba or its libraries .

```
grep -B10 samba- /var/log/apt/history.log
```

to make sure you've got last updates use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Also use:

```
apt changelog samba
```

or `aptitude changelog samba` if you are running an older version Ubuntu to get a list of last changes in this package, and if you pay attention you will see:

```
samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7) xenial-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: remote code execution from a writable share
  - debian/patches/CVE-2017-7494.patch: refuse to open pipe names with a
    slash inside in source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c.
  - CVE-2017-7494
```

Pay attention to the version: "*2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7*", Then use:

```
$ dpkg -l samba* | awk "( !(/none/) && /^ii/ )"
ii samba-libs:amd64  2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7 amd64  Samba core libraries
```

to see if you have patched version installed or not.

---

**Extra steps**

If you're really paranoia, grab a copy of source code, e.g:

```
apt source --download samba-libs
```

it will download the corresponding source code and all patches, extracts the source and apply the patches.

then go to:

```
head /path-to-extract/samba-4.3.11+dfsg/debian/changelog
```

You'll see the same stuff, as `apt changelog samba`. you can even look for patch itself:

```
cat /home/ravexina/samba-4.3.11+dfsg/debian/patches/CVE-2017-7494.patch

+   if (strchr(pipename, '/')) {
+       DEBUG(1, ("Refusing open on pipe %s\n", pipename));
+       return false;
+   }
+
```

or even compile and install it, if you wish.

---

If you're carious, you can see a proof of concept for cve-2017-7494 [here](https://github.com/omri9741/cve-2017-7494).

Comment: It should be aptitude changelog samba

Comment: Have you checked `apt`? Both `apt` and `apt-get` works fine...

Comment: `apt changelog samba` produces `E: Invalid operation changelog` in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I updated the answer with `aptitude` as an alternative ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Security Notice associated with the CVE has a list of affected Ubuntu releases and package versions where the patch was applied. From [USN-3296-1](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3296-1/):

> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following
>   package version:
>
> #### Ubuntu 17.04:
>
> samba 2:4.5.8+dfsg-0ubuntu0.17.04.2
>
> #### Ubuntu 16.10:
>
> samba 2:4.4.5+dfsg-2ubuntu5.6
>
> #### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
>
> samba 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7
>
> #### Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:
>
> samba 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.8

In addition, [USN-3296-2](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3296-2/) states that 12.04 ESM users also have a patched version available:

> #### Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:
>
> samba 2:3.6.25-0ubuntu0.12.04.11